# how to compare arrays in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've two arrays in angular2 like below

```
a[]=[{"alice",12},{"bob",15}];
b[]=[{"alice",12},{"james",16}];
```

How can i compare above two array using angular2 approach.
I need both values like matched value and unmatched values in angular2.

Comment: you mean you need the intersection and difference of the arrays?

Comment: yes , almost like that

Comment: I would suggest you get an utility library like lodash to do that for you.

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular? Or TypeScript for that matter? Angular is not a programming language. Generalized deep diffing is a complicated problem, but you could start off with a search for "deep comparison objects javascript".